# Is this character too cliche?

Tags: creative-writing, characters, antagonist, cliches, dark-fantasy

So I'm writing a story and my main antagonist is Death (At least from my MCs point of view). Is he as a antagonist too cliche? He owns a casino, his headquarters, and the setting is in 1700, London during a plague.

Comment: I'm imagining my Death as literal death personified and I am planning to later reveal that he was never the villain and in fact is more important than Life (opposite of Death)

Comment: Not Hades or the Devil, for Hades is portrayed as the Lord of The Underworld and the Devil is the King of Hell.

Comment: If anything he is more like Letum, Roman form of Thantos

Comment: Hmm... Interesting. But I don't think it is cliche at all. You should be fine! :)

Comment: This question is being discussed on [Meta](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2401/specific-cliche-requests-and-similar-questions-off-or-on-topic).

Comment: Thank You For Answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your character sounds a little like [Randall Flagg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randall_Flagg) from The Stand: Flagg makes Las Vegas his headquarters, and a plague is present. From the information given, I would imagine you have read the Stand.

Now, that doesn't make it cliché, as one can still only claim a similarity between the two characters (not a cliché). However, seeing how people are still reading the book, going on half a century after it's publication (it's still in almost every bookstore I've been to), how a TV-series was made of it 30 years ago, and how they made *another* TV-series out of it last year or so, you might risk people seeing as a cliché, even if it isn't one.

Comment: First off, I haven't read the Stand, sounds like an amazing book though, second off, I'm really invested into this story- how do I make it so my character doesn't seem too much like Randall Flagg?

Comment: That's for you to figure out; Where Randall's nuance lie, what you want to take from him, what not, etc. Either way, if the story you have in mind is freshly imagined (originality is extremely rare, to non-existent in narratives these days), then I see no reason why you shouldn't write it, regardless of what people might think of it in the end.